# Foreign Key - Alias viability?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Are you able to assign an alias to a foreign key?
e.g. "foreign key(campaign_id) references campaigns_Cmprsed (id)"
Since Campaign_id does not exist in the references table is there something like this that would exist?

"foreign key(campaign_id) references campaigns_Cmprsed (id as campaign_id)"

Comment: you do realise that redshift doesn't enforce these keys? The query planner MIGHT use them but it is critical that you enforce them externally to redshift - otherwise you could get incorrect results returned. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html . I suggest you don't bother unless you are really sure about why you are doing this.

Comment: Yes that is understood. We are using foreign keys for ERD diagram automation. To show relationships between tables. That is all.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you would want to create an alias for a column name when defining a foreign key?